# Simple way of extracting the a unique item from a C# list<T> with the total amout of items of that type

Tags: c#, linq, xna

Apologies if this is the incorrect place to ask; I am a very new hobbyist programmer.

I am current in my spare time working on a small top down shooting game, nothing more than a simple self driven project to learn and have fun with. I am using C# and XNA as a framework and I am trying to add a little variety to the game by picking up gameObjects to add to an inventory.

At the moment I have a single `List<GamePlayObjects>` "WorldObjects" and I have an `ObjectManager` class managing all objects updates, collisions and draw functions and im happy with what I have so far.  Upon collision with a GamePlayObject (example could be a small piece of Iron Ore after an asteroid has blown up) it removes the object from the primary list "WorldObjects" and add this to another list called `List<GamePlayObjects> inventory`

Now what I want to do is draw a small area on the screen with the items sprite and the total number of that item that I have collected. I am not really interested in the Drawing aspect is more of the extraction of the data in/out of the inventory.

I have read several threads on perhaps using `HashSet` to get unique items from my inventory and then extracting the total count of each item from the `HashSet`, but I'm struggling to comprehend this right now and hence my visit here for some assistance.

**Examples of my code and what im trying to achieve.**

I have a list of all of my WorldObjects each world Object is a Class holding everything related to that worlObject.

```
private List<GamePlayObject> gameObjects = new List<GamePlayObject>();
```

When One object, lets says the "Player" collides with another Object "Iron Ore" I remove the IronOre world Object from:

```
private List<GamePlayObject> gameObjects = new List<GamePlayObject>();
```

and add this to a new list called Inventory

```
private List<GamePlayObject> playerInventory = new List<GamePlayObject>();
```

Now as more and more objects are collected and added to my inventory I would like to extract information and display information about my inventory to the screen.

For example on the right hand side of my screen I would like to present a list of items that I have in my inventory and the total amount of each item, this data should be taken from my inventory list.

So it might look like this:

```
Iron Ore x 3
Steel x 10
Gold x 18
Uranium x 12
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now what I want to do is Draw a small area on the screen with the items sprite and the total number of that item that I have collected. I am not really interested in the Drawing aspect is more of the extraction of the data in/out of the inventory.

Sound like you want to use a linq count.

```
InventoryObjects.Count(inventoryObject => inventoryObject.Type == ObjectTypes.Asteroid);
WorldObjects.Count(worldObject => worldObject.Type == ObjectTypes.Asteroid);
```

You can think of this like SQL

SELECT COUNT([dbo].[World Objects].[Object]) WHERE [dbo].[World Objects].[Type]='Asteroid'

However, if you are looking to extract an item and add it to another list, you should take the advice of Reed Copsey.

---

**Edit**

So assuming that you have a `Player` Class then perhaps it structure like so,

```
Public Class Player {
    public List<GamePlayObject> Inventory {get; set;}
}
```

You also have a `World` Class and perhaps it has similar,

```
Public Class World {
    public List<GamePlayObject> Objects {get; set;}
}
```

Your `GamePlayObject` may look like so,

```
Public Class GamePlayObject {
    public ObjectType Type {get; set;}
}
```

So assuming you've initialized your world and it has several objects, and you know which object you wanted to remove from said World. This is certainly not be the best approach in terms of resources and optimization, (This would be where Reed Copsey's answer would come in handy) but, you could...

```
var targetObject = World.Where(gamePlayObject => (DesiredConditions))
World.Objects.Remove(targetObject);
Player.Inventory.Add(targetObject);
```

Where `DesiredConditions` would maybe be something like `gamePlayObject.IsCollidedWith`

Once you've done this you can query the `Player`'s inventory.

```
var IronCount = Player.Inventory.Count(gamePlayObject => gamePlayObject.Type == ObjectType.Iron);
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: +1. This is how I would have answered as well. Except using the `object` keyword as a variable. The compiler won't appreciate that.

Comment: Alex, many thanks but my knowledge of the usage of the above is very and I mean very limited at the moment. If my list has a list of "Iron, Iron, Steel,Gold,Gold,Gold" how can i create the following Iron x 2, Steel x 1 and Gold x 3, hope this makes sense.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `List<T>`, and use `List<T>.Remove`.  However, the problem with using a `List<T>` like this is that `Remove` will have to search the entire list, one item at a time, to find the item to remove.  This will also cause a large copy to occur, as the elements after the one you remove need to be shifted down in the internal array.

Collections like `HashSet<T>`, however, can find and remove items very quickly, without the copies.  This requires that your type implement `GetHashCode`, but would work better if you always want unique items.

One potential option, for both of your collections, would be to use a `Dictionary<GamePlayObject, int>`, which would allow you to quickly look up and change the number of that type of object within the world and the inventory.  Again, this would require that your `GamePlayObject` class override `object.GetHashCode` and `object.Equals`, and implement [`IEquatable<GamePlayObject>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Reed, I'm going to start research on :IEquatable<> and find how this works for my example above

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a great problem to solve with linq!  If you're new to linq, then I'd direct you to a great resource - 101 linq samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

On to your particular problem!  Since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can run linq queries on it.  Most interesting will be the grouping operators.

If your `GamePlayObject` class has a `Type` property, then you could do something like this:

```
var items = from o in playerInventory
    group o by o.Type into g
    select new { ItemType = g.Key, Items = g };
foreach (var g in items)
{
    string s = string.Format("{0} x {1}", g.ItemType.ToString(), g.Items.Count());
    //now do whatever you want with the string, which will contain, eg, Iron Ore x 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you probably should not be using a list. Meaning why iterate to and from one list to the order when what it seems like is you need to keep counts of the different gameplay objects.
I am presuming you have a fixed set of game play objects and they are uniquely named. You can have a fixed dictionaryof elements where you add or subtract counts meaning you would probably be doing something like this gameObjects ["ironore"]++ or playerInventory ["ironore"]--. And then you can use to linq to show  all keys whose values are greater than zero.